# Error executing SQL statement for: report name

Tags: java, ireport, jasper

Tengo un problema con la ejecución de un reporte en `Java`.

Quiero extraer todas las personas de "x" ciudad en un reporte generado con `JasperReport`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agrego un parámetro de tipo `String`, en este caso será por **CIUDAD**, y le añado en la consulta `SQL` con la condición `WHERE`.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Si realizo una prueba desde** "**Preview**", me pide el dato de tipo `String`, introduzco "SANTANDER" y me **muestra correctamente el reporte**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi duda es: ¿por qué desde un evento `ActionPerformed()` de un `JMenuItem` me muestra el siguiente error?

**Error:**

```
feb 15, 2022 8:42:26 PM interfaz.Index menu_ciudadActionPerformed
GRAVE: null
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error executing SQL statement for: report name.
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:367)
```

**Código:**

```
private void menu_ciudadActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        try {
            //iReports con parámetro.
            Connection c = (Connection) Conexiones.conexion_a_BBDD("clientesSL");
            JasperReport reporte = null;
            String path = "src\\reportes\\ReportePorCiudad.jasper";
            
            Map parametro = new HashMap();
            parametro.put("ciudad", "SANTANDER");
            
            reporte = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(path);
            JasperPrint jPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte, parametro, c);
            
            JasperViewer view = new JasperViewer(jPrint, false);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Reporte generado correctamente.", "Administrador", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            view.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            view.setVisible(true);
        } catch (JRException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Index.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: El parámetro debe ser sin signo de admiración: `$P{ciudad}`

Comment: @Sal Lo probé pero me sigue dando el mismo error.

Comment: Asumiendo que ya revisaste los parámetros de la conexión (usuario, contraseña, servidor, etc), pon en la pregunta la traza completa de la excepción.

Comment: @Sal El mundo de la tecnología..., borrando el .jrxml y volviendo a crear el jasper desde cero: ¡voilá, funcionó! Entonces no sé cuál fue el error... Cierro la pregunta. Gracias a todos.